Why is catch function called twice on the same promise?
I'm trying to understand how promises work under the hood in JS and faced with this example:
const promise = Promise.reject();

promise
  .catch(() => console.log(1));
  
promise
  .catch(() => console.log(2));

// Output:
// 1
// 2

const promise = Promise.reject();

promise
  .catch(() => console.log(1))
  .catch(() => console.log(2));

// Output:
// 1

Why do we have different outputs in similar examples?
Why catch is called second time in the first example?
Because promise is already rejected after the first catch, so it should be logical that the second catch should not be called in both cases...
I think the main reason here is how microtasks queue works but I'm not sure.

You're doing different things. In the first example you're calling the second .catch on the first promise, the one created by Promise.reject. In the second example you're calling the second .catch on the second promise, the one created by the first .catch (and which, crucially, resolves rather than rejecting).


Two catch handlers. When the promise rejects, they both trigger. 2. Two cascading catch handlers. If the promise rejects the first triggers and if and only if that  leads to a rejection, then the second will trigger.


"I think the main reason here is how microtasks queue works but I'm not sure." not everything is "microtask queue". I see users using the word as a substitute for "magic". Any time something well-defined and async (promises, or await) happens, they go "But is this microtask queue related?" instead of looking at what instructions they've given to JS. Because the microtask queue has extremely small impact on code. Way smaller than it's been attributed. Yes, it's a central part of how code is handled. But the vast majority of code can be understood without understanding the queue.

@jonrsharpe Why catch is called second time in the first example?
Because promise is already rejected after the first catch, so it should be logical that the second catch should not be called in both cases...

Every then or catch method on a Promise should eventually be executed. Lets say you store a fetch to a file somewhere and it errors out, do you want something else waiting for that file using that promise to not trigger the rror handling? If a promise fails it will call every handler registered ever to your catch handlers, and they return a new Promise (that would be resolved unless you throw an error). Best go and experiment a bit with these.

It boils down to this:

You can attach multiple callbacks to one promise. Yes, you can have several success and failure callbacks on the same promise, and they'll all be called once the promises either resolves or rejects.

In a promise chain, a catch in the chain will catch the propagation of rejections and continue on the successful path afterwards.


Your first case is an example of a promise chain fork:
promise → catch → ...
      ↳ catch → ...

You attach two catches to the same promise. Both will be called if the promise rejects. If you attach more callbacks to one or both catches, they'll be called depending on the result of your catch handler.
Your second case is a simple chain:
promise → catch → catch → ...

The first catch handler is called because the promise rejected. That handler doesn't produce any new errors, so the chain continues to the next success handler. Of which there is none, so nothing else happens.

This behavior is due to the microtask queue and how promises chaining works in JavaScript.
in the first example
Promise.reject() creates a rejected promise. This immediately schedules the catch handlers attached to the promise in the microtask queue for execution after the current synchronous code has finished.
promise.catch(() => console.log(1));
This schedules a microtask for the first catch handler to handle the rejection and log 1.
promise.catch(() => console.log(2));
This schedules another microtask for the second catch handler to handle the same rejection and log 2
in the second example
Promise.reject() creates a rejected promise. The rejection is scheduled to be handled in the microtask queue by the first catch handler.
promise.catch(() => console.log(1))
The first catch is chained to the promise. When the rejection is handled here and logs 1, the promise returned by this catch becomes a resolved promise.
.catch(() => console.log(2))
This catch is attached to the promise returned by the previous catch. Since the previous catch has resolved the promise, this catch is not triggered.

Talking about microtasks is superfluous to understanding this.

i.e. Promises behaved like this before the existence of the microtask queue
